# MVC5 ADFS with UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication: SecurityTokenReceivedendless loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, adfs

I am an ADFS noob, so please excuse any stupid questions.

I am trying to integrate with an ADFS server, so I've put this in the Startup.Auth.cs:

[image]

See that breakpoint line? It gets hit over and over again, until the server raises an error (it probably protects itself from multiple calls):
*Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: '"OpenIdConnectMessage.Error was not null, indicating an error. Error: 'server_error'. Error_Description (may be empty): 'MSIS9604%3a+An+error+occurred.+The+authorization+server+was+not+able+to+fulfill+the+request.'. Error_Uri (may be empty): 'error_uri is null'."'*

I really don't know what am I suppose to do, on classical logins, after checking the user exists in the database, I would do something like this to tell the app that I am logged in and to have access to all those [Authorize] controllers:

```
this.AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = rememberMe,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
        }, identity);
```

Do I have to do something similar here? I am in complete darkness, any help is appreciated.
Thanks

All links have trailing "/" (I read this might be an issue - if the "/" is missing)

Comment: Should I have something on the redirect URL? to "authenticate" the user somehow?

Comment: I got a little more insight. it seems that ADFS sets up a cookie, iis express does not recognize it or something, redirects back to adfs, it sets up another cookie and so on

Comment: Are you able to fix this? I am also facing this issue.